# Returning gocql's session variable from function

Tags: go, cassandra, cql

I have the following  gocql connection.

```
 //cassandra connection
  cluster := gocql.NewCluster("localhost")
  cluster.Keyspace = "demo"
  cluster.DefaultPort = 9042
  cluster.Consistency = gocql.Quorum
  session, _ = cluster.CreateSession()
  defer session.Close()
```

I want to put this inside a golang function and return the session variable,but I don't know its datatype. I tried returning ***Session** but it gives me an error. Any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation (http://godoc.org/github.com/gocql/gocql#ClusterConfig.CreateSession) the type is `*gocql.Session`. I would note, however, that if you defer the `session.Close()` call, it will run as soon as you return, meaning you will never return a valid connection. You will have to close the session in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

`cluster.CreateSession()` returns `*gocql.Session, error`

Maybe if you could share your actual code and tell us what error you are getting, this question would be easier to answer.

BTW there is a [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gocql) for more involved questions, as well as the [issue tracker](https://github.com/gocql/gocql/issues) on Github.